# Library Importing Error :Mlpy in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I used python version 2.7 and build a program. I used `pip install mlpy` to install the mlpy to my python version.
But `dtw_subsequence` is not there. Error came with no such module.

Then I use https://osdn.net/frs/g_redir.php?m=netix&f=%2Fmlpy%2Fmlpy+3.5.0%2Fmlpy-3.5.0.win32-py2.7.exe download and install. Error came as

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Is there any libraries that can use similar function `dtw_subsequence`?

my code

```
for fileName in os.listdir(dbPath):
    if fileName.endswith('.csv'):
        reference = manager.readMidi(dbPath, fileName)
        dist, cost, path = mlpy.dtw_subsequence(record, reference)
        temp.append([int(dist), fileName[:-10]])
return temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think mlpy is not installed when you used pip install mlpy. you can try using easy_install mlpy.

If it still doesn't work you can download the latest version rom http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: after I installed using this ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. error occured. when I try to run my program.

Comment: This error occur mlpy unable to import gsl. I tried to install that using cmd. But it is also not worked.

Comment: Try below commands on cmd    pip install wheel ,    uninstall already existing numpy,scipy,mlpy and download mlpy.whl,Numpy+MKL.whl,scipy.whl files from mlpy.http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  then  use pip install *.whl for all the 3 whl files.  This worked for me                                    >>> import mlpy
>>> mlpy.dtw_subsequence([1,2,3],[2,3,4])
(1.0, array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  2.]]), (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 1])))

Comment: Thank you. But Still same problem